# How to change tables and cells styles all at once by using Java script?

Tags: indesign-scripting

How to change tables and cells styles all at once by using Java script?
I want a dialogue box to enter stroke weight.
Thank you

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site. Please give us a little more information. Normally you would use *Table Style* and *Cell Style* to change all similar tables at once. Is there a reason why you can't do that? Many tables with no styling perhaps? And please tell us what you have tried to make your script work. How far have you come? Do you know scripting in InDesign?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.
I have a 50 pages file with many tables and have different stroke weight. So I want a javascript to change all strokes (pop-up dialogue box to add required stroke weight) at once with a single click.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming.

Answer (score 1):

This little snippet should do what you want:

```js
var sw = prompt("Enter stroke weight in points.", 1);

var c = app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().cells.everyItem();

c.bottomEdgeStrokeWeight = c.leftEdgeStrokeWeight = c.rightEdgeStrokeWeight = c.topEdgeStrokeWeight = sw;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working now

Comment: In this case you could mark the answer as accepted, so others will know that the issue is solved. :)